# Grails 3.* - Creating custom property file and read the data

Tags: grails, properties, grails-3.0

I am  using Grails 3.1, trying to create a custom property file and read the data present in that file.

File `myapp.properties` is located in the config directory and contains data such as

```
name = "abc"
```

I want to read the data in my controller.

Any suggestions is appreciated

Comment: Why do you need a custom properties file? why don't you use the standard `propertyplaceholderconfigurer` mechanism and place your properties in your `application.groovy`? See https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/spring.html

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is probably with Spring Boot's `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Put your `myapp.properties` in `src/main/resources` then create a configuration class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(locations=['classpath:myapp.properties'])
class MyConfiguration {
   String name
}
```

Add it as a Spring bean in `grails-app/resources.groovy`

```
myConfiguration(MyConfiguration)
```

Auto wire it into a controller or service:

```
@Autowired
MyConfiguration myConfiguration

def foo() {
   render myConfiguration.name
}
```